# PHP Date / Time Problem

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

So I'm trying to get the difference in days for the following dates. For one of them it works, but for the other the number is off. It should be 3.

I could use the `ceil` function, but I still don't know why the following isn't correct.

```
$checkOut = strtotime('2011-02-16');
$checkIn = strtotime('2011-02-11');
echo ($checkOut - $checkIn) / (60 * 60 * 24); // => 5
echo floor(($checkOut - $checkIn)/(60*60*24)); // => 5

$checkOut = strtotime('2011-03-14');
$checkIn = strtotime('2011-03-11');
echo ($checkOut - $checkIn) / (60 * 60 * 24); // => 2.958333333
echo floor(($checkOut - $checkIn)/(60*60*24)); // => 2
```

Comment: That is it! Thanks! Although the PHP spec says that `strtotime` returns seconds since epoch, but I guess that is not the case.

Comment: Seams to work here http://ideone.com/ai3jo, outputs 3 for both

Comment: I get 3 when I do that second block, as expected

Comment: @James it is returing seconds since epoch, but it is interpreting the input date as being in a certain timezone (which may not be UTC)

Comment: Ah, good points. Not sure what PHP versions our production systems are using, but assuming it works if I specify UTC, I'll just do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the php object-oriented [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)?

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2011-03-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2011-03-14');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)() for that problem.

By using floor() you're essentially getting the next lower integer (cutting away everything after the comma).

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is because it crosses daylight savings time. Although the PHP spec says that strtotime returns seconds since epoch, I guess that is not the case.

Comment: Uhm, of course it returns the seconds since epoch. The switch from/to DST makes one day 3600 seconds shorter/longer, so those 3600 seconds are missing in that "seconds since epoch".

Comment: Um... I don't believe that is true, even according to the definition that I gave. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time